# Affiness, $U_{2,4}$ and $M(K_4).$

Tags: projective-geometry, affine-geometry, algebraic-graph-theory, matroids, algebraic-combinatorics

I do not know why $M(K_4)$ is not affine over $GF(2)$ or $GF(3)$ but it is affine over all fields with more than 3 elements. I proved that $U_{2,4}$ is $\mathbb F$-representable iff $|\mathbb F| \geq 3.$

Is there any coincidence between the numbers that help in concluding why $M(K_4)$ is not affine over $GF(2)$ or $GF(3)$ but it is affine over all fields with more than 3 elements?

Any explanation will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that $M$ is $\mathbb{F}$-representable iff it is a restriction of $PG(r(M)-1, \mathbb{F})$?

Comment: Yes I am @MathieuRundström

Comment: but I still do not see what you are trying to tell me @MathieuRundström